# Using fscanf to read from /proc C++

Tags: c++, scanf

I am currently getting started on writing a program that will read info from `/proc` using `fscanf` and I am not sure where to start. Looking through the man page for `proc(5)`, I noticed that you can use `fscanf` to get certain attributes from the `/proc` directory.

For example `MemTotal %lu` gets the total usable amount of RAM if you were reading `proc/meminfo`. Then would the `fscanf` would look like:

```
unsigned long memTotal=0;
FILE* file = fopen("/proc/meminfo", "r");
fscanf(file, "MemTotal %lu", &memTotal);
```

How would I iterate over the file while using `fscanf` to get certain values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some code to do exactly [well, it wasn't exactly `"/proc/meminfo"`, but reading data from a `"/proc/something"` using `scanf`] this at work the other day.

The principle is to check the return value of `fscanf`. It will be either EOF, 0 or 1 for End of input, didn't get anything and found what you were looking for. If the result is EOF, you exit the loop. If it's 0 for all of your sampling points, you will need to do something else to skip the line - I use a loop around `fgetc()` to read the line.

If you want to read several elements, it's probably best to do that using some kind of list.

I'd probably do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned long* value>> list = 
    { { "MemTotal %lu", &memTotal },
      { "MemFree %lu",  &memFree },
      ...
    };

bool done = false
while(!done)
{ 
     int res = 0;

     bool found_something = false;
     for(auto i : list)
     {
        res = fscanf(file, i.first.c_str(), i.second);
        if (res == EOF)
        {
           done = true;
           break;
        }
        if (res != 0)
        {
           found_something = true;
        }
     }
     if (!found_something)
     {
         // Skip line that didn't contain what we were looking for.
         int ch;
         while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
         {
             if (ch == '\n')
                break;
         }
     }
}
```

This is just a sketch of how to do this, but it should give you an idea.